# OBD Response for 01 0D is not recognized

Tags: diagnostics, obd-ii

Trying to build a small app via PhoneGap which connects to OBD via BlueTooth and just getting the current speed.

It works fine on one of my test adapters but the second one gives weird responses (both are v1.5):

```
SENT ATZ
15:32:02.421 "ELM327 v1.5\r\n>  
SENT AT SP 0
15:32:03.106 "SEARCHING...\r\n41 0D 00 \r\n\r\n>"", 
SENT AT DP 
15:32:03.129 "AUTO,ISO 15765-4 (CAN 11/500)\r\n>
SENT 01 0D
15:32:03.781 "61 8E FF \r\n\r\n>
15:32:04.767 "61 8D FD \r\n\r\n>
15:32:05.782 "61 8F 00 \r\n\r\n>
15:32:06.766 "61 8E FF \r\n\r\n>
15:32:07.767 "61 8D FD \r\n\r\n>
15:32:08.758 "61 8F 00 \r\n\r\n>
15:32:09.751 "61 8E FF \r\n\r\n>
15:32:10.780 "61 8D FD \r\n\r\n>
15:32:11.753 "61 8F 00 \r\n\r\n>
15:32:12.755 "61 8E FF \r\n\r\n>
15:32:13.748 "61 8D FD \r\n\r\n>
15:32:14.746 "61 8F 00 \r\n\r\n>
```

The other adapter is responding as expected (41 0D XX) after sending 01 0D.

What are these 61 XX XX codes trying to tell me? Why are these three (8F 00, 8E FF, 8D FD)looping? I read the documentation of the ELM327 but either I don't understand it or the values are not regulary part of the answer of 01 0D.

I used the app Torque to check the adapter, it took longer than usual to connect but finally it worked as intended.

So - what do I have to send to get the speed?

Thanks in advance, 
Jonas

Comment: Are you sure that no other process is communicating with the adapter in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what kind of adapters and car, you're seeing other CAN messages, you need to filter for the specific addresses you want to deal with.  Try turning on the headers with the ATH1 command.